# compilation error while #import tlb file in COM automation

Tags: c++, com, typelib

I am trying to #include an application tlb file in VC++ project.

Getting following compilation errors, after #import "CANoe.tlb" in my project source file. -

- unknown character '0x1'
- syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'A'
- missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Please suggest, if I am doing some wrong.

Also, is there a way to verify the .tlb file contents and resolve these errors. Is it possible to make corrections in tlb file ? If so, how do I create a updated tlb

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use OleView to look into the tlb. Correcting the tlb is a pain if ever possible. But once you identify the source of the problem you can play with the attributes of the import directive (all described in MSDN) to try to work it around.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is that you are dealing with a file that is not a TLB.  Or at least, is corrupted.

I would try and bring up the TLB in OleView.  This should give you a quick sanity check that the TLB is or is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If the type library file is intact the next step is to try find the generated .tlh and .tli files - they will be located in some temporary folder and have the same name as type library file and ".tlh"/".tli" extensions. If they exist examining them might help a lot.

`import` directive does two things - it builds the ".tlh" and ".tli" files and then includes them - the error messages correspond to the second stage - when the C++ compiler just refuses to compile them. Examining the files will likely help identify the reason.